# adding momentum to back propagation algorithm

Tags: neural-network

To speed up the process of learning,the momentum term is added to the weight update rule.

```
      W_deltaJI(n) = LR * error(J) * InputIJ + momentum*W_deltaJI(n-1)
```

Here,

Does the W_deltaJI(n) needs to be accumulated for each training packet?

Comment: What do you mean by training 'packet'? Are you asking if you need to compute this error function for every labeled example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean each training cycle on a pattern set.

If you are trying to do something fancy like batch backpropagation with momentum then the answer would be yes. You would accumulate the weight matrices and apply the momentum term at the end of each cycle. This might be efficient for huge and complex data sets.

Normal momentum term training updates W_deltaJI(n) on the fly, per cycle. So for neural net learning purposes you would not need to accumulate.

Comment: So, in the normal case(online updates), what does n and n-1 mean ? Are they consecutive training sets ? Thanks . .

Comment: n is the training step at which the delta is being applied. So yes n-1 is the previous training step.